# Why consult-recent-file show also recent directories?

Tags: recentf, consult

Emacs 27.1

package: consult ver.0.32

Here my init.el

```
(use-package consult
  :config (message "consult - I'm always here after the package is loaded")
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (recentf-add-file default-directory)))
  (define-key consult-narrow-map (vconcat consult-narrow-key "?") #'consult-narrow-help)
 )

(use-package consult-dir
  :ensure t
  :bind (("C-x C-d" . consult-dir)
     ("C-x C-j" . consult-dir-dired)
         :map minibuffer-local-completion-map
         ("C-x C-d" . consult-dir)
     ("C-x C-j" . consult-dir-dired)))

(use-package consult-project-extra
  :ensure t
  :bind
  (("C-c p f" . consult-project-extra-find)
   ("C-c p o" . consult-project-extra-find-other-window)))
```

[image]

```
M-x consult-recent-file
```

[image]

Why also show recent directories. I need to show only recent files!

If I remove

```
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (recentf-add-file default-directory)))
```

than it work fine.

But I need this config, because recent directories not working correctly:

```
  M-x consult-dir
  Press "r"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `recentf` (wrapped by `consult-recent-file`) behavior is correct since you are adding `directory` (where `recentf-add-file` expects `file`) in order to change the behavior of `consult-dir` as you wish.
Then, how about just erasing the directory and put it back using something like "recentf-remove-file", the opposite of `recentf-add-file` when you finish using `consult-dir`(or before using `consult-recent-file`)? I found `recentf-remove-if-non-kept` that is close to that purpose. Here is the modified one can be used for that just by removing condition (the original lines are commented out) and you can find a suitable hook to add `(recentf-remove default-directory)`:

```lisp
;; (defsubst recentf-remove-if-non-kept (filename)
(defun recentf-remove (filename)
  "Remove FILENAME from the recent list"
  ;; , if file is not kept.Return non-nil if FILENAME has been removed."
  ;; (unless (recentf-keep-p filename)
  (let ((m (recentf-string-member
            (recentf-expand-file-name filename) recentf-list)))
    (and m (setq recentf-list (delq (car m) recentf-list)))))
;; )
```

Comment: When try to execute this function I get error: Debugger entered--Lisp error: (scan-error "Unbalanced parentheses" 546 1)

Comment: Since the number of opening parentheses and closing one of the above snippet are the same and balanced (There are 11 of each, right?), I can't imagine what is happening on your end. As a minimum test, what happens when you enter `C-x C-e` (to call `eval-last-sexp`) at the end of the snippet? Then likewise enter `C-x C-e` at each end of `(recentf-add-file default-directory)` and `(recentf-remove default-directory)`, where does it go wrong?